# Can tasks from the Android Plugin for Gradle be marked as cacheable?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

The Gradle build cache was introduced in version 3.5.
It's now simple to setup a remote (shared) build cache as introduced in this [article](https://blog.gradle.org/introducing-gradle-build-cache),
and shown in this [repository](https://github.com/gradle/task-output-cache-demos).
While the demonstration Java project produces the desired output:

```
:compileJava FROM-CACHE
```

All Android projects I've tried produce approximately 90% `not cacheable` tasks.

Can these Android specific tasks be made cacheable?

To add Gradle 3.6 to an Android project, edit `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` with: `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions-snapshots/gradle-3.6-20170314000035+0000-bin.zip`. This works with the latest Android Studio (Canary) 2.4 preview 7.

Comment: I haven't played with this. My guess is that the tasks themselves need to be modified, which would be the Android tools teams' responsibility. On the whole, they seem to be leaning more towards tightly-scoped builds (e.g., Instant Run), which may or may not help with cross-machine caching.